Multiple Errors Encountered During npm start Execution - How to Resolve?
./node_modules/@kolkov/angular-editor/fesm2015/kolkov-angular-editor.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@kolkov\angular-editor\fesm2015\kolkov-angular-editor.mjs: This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 14.0.1, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.
Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular.
463 | }
464 | AeSelectComponent.ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "14.0.1", ngImport: i0, type: AeSelectComponent, deps: [{ token: i0.ElementRef }, { token: i0.Renderer2 }], target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Component });

465 | AeSelectComponent.ɵcmp = i0.ɵɵngDeclareComponent({ minVersion: "14.0.0", version: "14.0.1", type: AeSelectComponent, selector: "ae-select", inputs: { options: "options", isHidden: ["hidden", "isHidden"] }, outputs: { changeEvent: "change" }, host: { listeners: { "document:click": "onClick($event)", "keydown": "handleKeyDown($event)" }, properties: { "style.display":[39m "this.hidden" } }, providers: [
|                          ^
466 |         {
467 |             provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
468 |             useExisting: forwardRef(() => AeSelectComponent),'
at run (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:37:15)
at run.next ()
at Function.transform (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transform.js:25:41)
at transform.next ()
at step (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
at C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:273:13
at async.call.result.err.err (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)
at C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:37:40

./node_modules/ng-apexcharts/fesm2015/ng-apexcharts.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\ng-apexcharts\fesm2015\ng-apexcharts.mjs: This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 15.2.9, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.
Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular.
164 | }
165 | /** @nocollapse */ ChartComponent.ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "15.2.9", ngImport: i0, type: ChartComponent, deps: [{ token: i0.NgZone }], target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Component });

166 | /** @nocollapse */ ChartComponent.ɵcmp = i0.ɵɵngDeclareComponent({ minVersion: "14.0.0", version: "15.2.9", type: ChartComponent, selector: "apx-chart", inputs: { chart: "chart", annotations: "annotations", colors: "colors", dataLabels: "dataLabels", series: "series", stroke: "stroke", labels: "labels", legend: "legend", markers: "markers", noData: "noData", fill: "fill", tooltip: "tooltip", plotOptions: "plotOptions", responsive: "responsive", xaxis: "xaxis", yaxis: "yaxis", forecastDataPoints: "forecastDataPoints", grid: "grid", states: "states", title: "title", subtitle: "subtitle", theme: "theme", autoUpdateSeries: "autoUpdateSeries" },
outputs: { chartReady: "chartReady" }, viewQueries: [{ propertyName: "chartElement", first: true, predicate: ["chart"], descendants: true, static: true }], usesOnChanges: true, ngImport: i0, template: <div #chart></div>, isInline: true, changeDetection: i0.ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush });
|                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
167 | i0.ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "15.2.9", ngImport: i0, type: ChartComponent, decorators: [{
168 |             type: Component,
169 |             args: [{'
at run (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:37:15)
at run.next ()
at Function.transform (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transform.js:25:41)
at transform.next ()
at step (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
at C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:273:13
at async.call.result.err.err (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)
at C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:37:40

./node_modules/ngx-print/fesm2022/ngx-print.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\ngx-print\fesm2022\ngx-print.mjs: This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 17.0.4, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.
Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular.
382 |     }
383 |     static ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "17.0.4", ngImport: i0, type: NgxPrintDirective, deps: null, target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Directive });

384 |     static ɵdir = i0.ɵɵngDeclareDirective({ minVersion: "14.0.0", version: "17.0.4", type: NgxPrintDirective, isStandalone: true, selector: "button[ngxPrint]", inputs: { previewOnly: "previewOnly", printSectionId: "printSectionId", printTitle: "printTitle", useExistingCss: "useExistingCss", printDelay: "printDelay", closeWindow: "closeWindow", bodyClass: "bodyClass", openNewTab: "openNewTab", printStyle: "printStyle", styleSheetFile: "styleSheetFile" }, host: { listeners: { "click": "print()" } }, usesInheritance: true, ngImport: i0 });
|                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
385 | }
386 | i0.ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "17.0.4", ngImport: i0, type: NgxPrintDirective, decorators: [{
387 |             type: Directive,'
at run (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:37:15)
at run.next ()
at Function.transform (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transform.js:25:41)
at transform.next ()
at step (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
at C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:273:13
at async.call.result.err.err (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)
at C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:37:40

Error: node_modules/@kolkov/angular-editor/lib/ae-button/ae-button.component.d.ts:9:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires 7 type argument(s)../node_modules/@kolkov/angular-editor/fesm2015/kolkov-angular-editor.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@kolkov\angular-editor\fesm2015\kolkov-angular-editor.mjs: This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 14.0.1, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.
Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular.
463 | }
464 | AeSelectComponent.ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "14.0.1", ngImport: i0, type: AeSelectComponent, deps: [{ token: i0.ElementRef }, { token: i0.Renderer2 }], target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Component });

465 | AeSelectComponent.ɵcmp = i0.ɵɵngDeclareComponent({ minVersion: "14.0.0", version: "14.0.1", type: AeSelectComponent, selector: "ae-select", inputs: { options: "options", isHidden: ["hidden", "isHidden"] }, outputs: { changeEvent: "change" }, host: { listeners: { "document:click": "onClick($event)", "keydown": "handleKeyDown($event)" }, properties: { "style.display":[39m "this.hidden" } }, providers: [
|                          ^
466 |         {
467 |             provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
468 |             useExisting: forwardRef(() => AeSelectComponent),'
at run (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:37:15)
at run.next ()
at Function.transform (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transform.js:25:41)
at transform.next ()
at step (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
at C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:273:13
at async.call.result.err.err (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)
at C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:37:40

./node_modules/ng-apexcharts/fesm2015/ng-apexcharts.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\ng-apexcharts\fesm2015\ng-apexcharts.mjs: This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 15.2.9, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.
Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular.
164 | }
165 | /** @nocollapse */ ChartComponent.ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "15.2.9", ngImport: i0, type: ChartComponent, deps: [{ token: i0.NgZone }], target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Component });

166 | /** @nocollapse */ ChartComponent.ɵcmp = i0.ɵɵngDeclareComponent({ minVersion: "14.0.0", version: "15.2.9", type: ChartComponent, selector: "apx-chart", inputs: { chart: "chart", annotations: "annotations", colors: "colors", dataLabels: "dataLabels", series: "series", stroke: "stroke", labels: "labels", legend: "legend", markers: "markers", noData: "noData", fill: "fill", tooltip: "tooltip", plotOptions: "plotOptions", responsive: "responsive", xaxis: "xaxis", yaxis: "yaxis", forecastDataPoints: "forecastDataPoints", grid: "grid", states: "states", title: "title", subtitle: "subtitle", theme: "theme", autoUpdateSeries: "autoUpdateSeries" },
outputs: { chartReady: "chartReady" }, viewQueries: [{ propertyName: "chartElement", first: true, predicate: ["chart"], descendants: true, static: true }], usesOnChanges: true, ngImport: i0, template: <div #chart></div>, isInline: true, changeDetection: i0.ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush });
|                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
167 | i0.ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "15.2.9", ngImport: i0, type: ChartComponent, decorators: [{
168 |             type: Component,
169 |             args: [{'
at run (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:37:15)
at run.next ()
at Function.transform (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transform.js:25:41)
at transform.next ()
at step (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
at C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:273:13
at async.call.result.err.err (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)
at C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:37:40

./node_modules/ngx-print/fesm2022/ngx-print.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\ngx-print\fesm2022\ngx-print.mjs: This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 17.0.4, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.
Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular.
382 |     }
383 |     static ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "17.0.4", ngImport: i0, type: NgxPrintDirective, deps: null, target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Directive });

384 |     static ɵdir = i0.ɵɵngDeclareDirective({ minVersion: "14.0.0", version: "17.0.4", type: NgxPrintDirective, isStandalone: true, selector: "button[ngxPrint]", inputs: { previewOnly: "previewOnly", printSectionId: "printSectionId", printTitle: "printTitle", useExistingCss: "useExistingCss", printDelay: "printDelay", closeWindow: "closeWindow", bodyClass: "bodyClass", openNewTab: "openNewTab", printStyle: "printStyle", styleSheetFile: "styleSheetFile" }, host: { listeners: { "click": "print()" } }, usesInheritance: true, ngImport: i0 });
|                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
385 | }
386 | i0.ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "17.0.4", ngImport: i0, type: NgxPrintDirective, decorators: [{
387 |             type: Directive,'
at run (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:37:15)
at run.next ()
at Function.transform (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transform.js:25:41)
at transform.next ()
at step (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
at C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:273:13
at async.call.result.err.err (C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)
at C:\Users\faysal\Desktop\stage\Doccerts-Frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:37:40

Error: node_modules/@kolkov/angular-editor/lib/ae-button/ae-button.component.d.ts:9:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires 7 type argument(s).
